# Web workers for HTML5 game physics simulation?

Tags: physics, javascript, html5

A bit related to this [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step).

The idea is to guarantee the same physics behavior as much as possible. Would it be possible to run fixed time step physics on a web worker? The UI would update itself with different/variable refresh rate.

Has anyone tried such yet?

Comment: What do you presume to gain by using a web worker? So far my answer would be, that'll work, but why bother?

Answer (score 3):

This could work, however `WebWorker`s follow the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), the `document` (html page that owns the worker) can only listen and post messages to/from a worker. From that, there's a few options, I guess. In all cases I think you will need to find someway to determine the optimal FPS of the user agent in order to optimize the information. Then you could either:

- Tell the workers to post messages at those time intervals

  - Downside(s?): you have to assume that the `document` will be ready for the response when it happens.
- Tell the `document` to send a message to the worker requesting physics at time interval `x`, then the worker would post a response (hopefully) shortly after that.

  - Downside(s?): since all posts and responses are asyncronous, there may be delays between the request and response from the worker. In this case you would also have to null out the `onmessage` event to prevent your `document` from listening when it doesn't expect to be.

I'm sure there's other things I missed or ways to handle communications as well. I'll be looking forward to other answers on the subject myself!

Comment: a) Caution regarding performance! Consider requestAnimationFrame and signal a 'keep alive' to your worker from it, so that you don't burn CPU if the tab is placed in the background (perhaps for too long)

Comment: b) IIRC All messages from the worker will be received on the main thread, they'll queue up. Think about what impact that will have on your main thread, if you got 5 updates but only need the latest. You also can't tell that you have more coming.

Comment: c) All messages are making copies of data. The more data you have to send between threads the more data copying and garbage collection work. So, a win here will only exist if there is a high computation / message data ratio.

Comment: @Vincent, regarding B) that's why I said that you would either need to have `document` always ready by finding a reasonable fps or go with option 2 where the worker does nothing until `document` asks for it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this [experiment](http://extremelysatisfactorytotalitarianism.com/blog/?p=932). It runs Box2d physics on a web worker. I haven't yet checked in the detail how it gets around issues mentioned in Vincent Scheib's comments.

Comment: Good experiment. I've been following these types of projects too. Unfortunately, most are still tied to Java/C. I believe that OP is looking for a way to pull this off natively in the browser (no plugins).

Comment: Article about the same by a google guy: http://t.co/AuhPptB

Answer (score 2):

[Physijs](http://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs) uses a web worker. It glues together ammojs physics with Three.js objects and updates them as need be. It features both fixed and fluid time steps, I believe