# Incrase framerate in XNA

Tags: xna, c#, frame-rate

I'm trying to increase the frame rate of my game from 60FPS to 100 FPS because of reasons. But i can't seem to get it higher than 60 frames. [This](http://pastebin.com/UVJ3gpWp) is the count I'm using. I can slow down the frame rate by setting `TargetElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 16);`

to a higher value, but settings it lower won't increase the frame rate, according to the counter. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: May I ask the reason why you're wanting to increase the frame rate?

Comment: Mostly because of animation reasons but also game mechanics reasons.

Comment: @Subsequent Animation should generally be tied to time, not frame count. Physics can be tied to a fixed frame rate to make it deterministic, but it still shouldn't matter whether you use 60 or 100 fps.

Comment: I need to apply updates on certain frames of the animation.

Comment: You're "frame counting" rather than compensating for time. This will introduce more issues than you are trying to solve. You should use gameTime.ElapsedGameTime to see how much time passed since the last frame. 100FPS is not guaranteed even on a device that is capable of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found I had to do the following to set the FPS limit free. In your [`Game`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.aspx) class, do the following:

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);  // I have this stored as a member variable
graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false;
IsFixedTimeStep = false;
```

Note that an unlimited FPS can cause unpredictability in physic engines, and network games. A full discussion of fixed vs variable timesteps can be found here: [When should I use a fixed or variable time step?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step)

Comment: Oho, apparently i had placed the bools in the loadcontent method which seems to have prevented them from changing the settings. I moved them to the constructor and now it works... |(\ strange that it didn't give me an error though

Comment: @Subsequent See this answer for how `GraphicsDeviceManager` works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11287316/165500 (it's about resolution, but it applies to all settings, including vsync).

Comment: @Andrew Russell Thank you, very informative. I just started working with C# and XNA a week ago, but i have some prior experience with C and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

The FPS is capped at 60 because of the default value of `true` on `Game.IsFixedTimeStep`. If you set this value to `false` it should allow your FPS to go to whatever you need it to.

[Game.IsFixedTimeStep on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.isfixedtimestep.aspx)

Comment: I did that as well, but it still says 60FPS on the counter

Comment: @Subsequent Set `GraphicsDeviceManager.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace` to false as well, and if that doesn't work then your gpu driver might be forcing vsync. You could disable that for your own computer, but you can't guarantee that every computer will do that. Just one of the joys of gamedev right there.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't help either. But would my GPU affect all the programs on my computer then? Because i have another game that runs at 100FPS without problem.