# Can someone provide a practical example of decoupling game world updates from frame redraws in iOS?

Tags: ios, game-loop, spritekit

Please bear with me as I've been spending some time lately trying to get a better grasp of some game dev fundamentals. My specific issue is a direct result of trying to apply what I've read about here: [When should I use a fixed or variable time step?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step)

I understand that a common option is to write your game framerate-dependent and be done with it. However, once you mix in `SKAction`'s or physics bodies, this seems like a good way for things to get out of sync. For example, one scenario I can think of is something like an endless runner where the earth is moving beneath you at a steady rate (`.position.x -= someDistance`) mixed with other objects whose positions are updated with a `[SKAction moveTo: duration:]`, or physics bodies whose positions are updated by applying a force/impulse.

So it makes sense to me that the solution to this problem is to decouple game world updates from frame redraws. This means *not* using `[SKScene update:]` for world updates and instead coming up with your own game loop.

So I guess my question is twofold. Am I on the right track or am I off-base with any of my assumptions? Does Sprite Kit have a game loop set up outside of `[SKScene update:]` that is redraw independent, and whose resolution I can specify, that I can leverage? `NSTimer` has turned out to be way too inaccurate in my tests. Specifically a practical example would be great.

Comment: Are you taking into account the ellapsed game time in your calculations of velocity?

Comment: Based on my understanding, what I believe I should implement is option 3 in this answer: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/1619/54348 Option 1 is *not* an option because of what I describe above and that is that `SKAction`'s and physics bodies are updated independently of framerate (as well they should). So I'm trying to better understand where and how to implement such a solution as that option in iOS. Or more specifically, how I would set up such an update loop outside of `[SKScene update:]` or am I even grasping the concept correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend a bit more time on this and I do think I was making a few wrong assumptions. First of all, I think one big mistake was in thinking that I should avoid `[SKScene update:]` for framerate-independence. But since iOS devices are vsync'ed, and the update method is coupled to screen redraws, I can reliably expect that that method will fire every 1/60th of a second (60fps) at best, and when performance degrades, it'll step down in discrete increments. That is: 30fps (60/2), then 20fps (60/3), then 15fps (60/4), etc. This is because if load is too much that an updated frame 1/60th of a second later is not ready - whatever was drawn last is repeated - the next opportunity to draw an update only comes 1/60th of a second after that and so on.

So what this tells me is that I should always be able to figure out the number of frames I need to catch up to. My understanding now is that this is what an accumulator does. Anyhow, here's the code more or less:

```
var lastTime: CFTimeInterval = 0.0
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (lastTime == 0.0) { lastTime = currentTime }

    var accumulatedFrames = round((currentTime - lastTime) * 60.0) // assume updates at 60hz and catch up if we drop below that

    lastTime = currentTime // for the next update

    // update the world as many times needed to "catch up"
    while (accumulatedFrames > 0) {
        updateMyWorld()
        accumulatedFrames--
    }
}
```

It appears to be working well but I would love if someone could confirm my approach.