# What is the difference between framerate independent vs framerate dependent?

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, frame-rate

What is the difference between framerate independent vs framerate dependent? 
Can you please give an example.

Comment: Our [most viewed question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step) sounds pretty similar. Does it help?

Answer (score 3):

See the answer linked in the comments on your question for a detailed answer. Here is an undetailed answer:

Say a character is moving to the right along the x axis. You move it at 1 pixel per frame. In 60 frames, it will be 60 pixels to the right of where it started. If you are running at 60 FPS, it will arrive at its destination in 1 second. If you are running at 30 frames per second, it will take 2 seconds to reach its destination. This is generally not ideal. (Frame rate dependent)

If you multiply that pixels per frame by the duration of the frame (in milliseconds), it will arrive at its destination in the same amount of time, regardless of frame rate (FPS). (Frame rate independent)

Comment: How the independent frame rate affected to the velocity? if i set velocity for one object with damping = 0,3 . what should i do to get exactly the object location? I'm getting inconsistent result from `setVelocity`