# delta_time with discrete movement

Tags: python, pygame

I have a basic snake game movement system with Pygame:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
if timer == MOVE_TICK_INTERVAL:
    timer = 0
    move_snake()

timer += 1
clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
```

The issue is that the higher `MAX_FPS` is, the faster `timer` iterates and thus the faster the snake moves. I'm aware of using some form of `delta_time` variable to calibrate and adjust the velocity of an object moving continuously but I don't know how to implement this method with discrete, grid-based movement.

In short,
I want to move my snake the same amount of units in a direction every interval with frame rate considered but I don't want to modify said distance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a fixed or variable time step?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/when-should-i-use-a-fixed-or-variable-time-step)

Comment: I'm having trouble relating the article in question with my issue. Potentially due to my lack of game design knowledge.

Comment: Your problem, at least to me, is a very fundamental question about the way a gameloop works, and is usually solved by either a fixed or a variable time step approach described in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly straightforward to convert this to use the real-time clock.  The PyGame `time` object has a `get_ticks()` member function which returns a continuously updating count of milliseconds.  It's quite handy for timing objects in games.

Basing your movement on a number of milliseconds makes the updating completely independent of the frame rate.  So if your FPS drops a fraction because the device needs to do something in the background, the movement is still constant.

```
MOVE_TICK_INTERVAL = 300   # milliseconds between player movements
next_move_at       = 0     # time in future when player move occurrs

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# in main loop
time_now_ms = pygame.time.get_ticks()

# is it time to move the player?
if ( time_now_ms > next_move_at ):
    new_move_at = time_now_ms + MOVE_TICK_INTERVAL   # future time of next move
    move_snake()

clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
```